# Xamarin - How to execute API?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm new in xamarin and developed app in visual studio,I wanna know how to execute API and how to retrieve Json response give some example,Is there any Libraries.

Comment: Have you done any research before asking this question? Typing the exact same question in Google gives you tons of answers.  Please refer to this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For networking you can use common for .NET [WebClient](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/System.Net.WebClient/). Any article will be applicable.

[Json.Net](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) do great job on any .net platform also.